# Getting empty response when sending request to "Get Suites by Test Case ID"

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am working with an API to create/update TFS test cases and lots of times the Outcome of newly created ones stays as Active instead the real test result.
That happens because after receiving a `workitem.created` event from TFS webhooks I perform a request to endpoint `_apis/test/suites?testCaseId={testCaseId}` but I got the following response: `{"value":[],"count":0}`.

It might be just a time issue.

Does anyone have any idea what could be done to handle that?

Comment: Since we suspected this is a time issue, have you tried rerun the Get Suites by Test Case ID api? When rerun the api, are you able to get the expected response?

Comment: I've added a loop to repeat the request 60 times, but didn't try something like `Thread.Sleep` or  `Task.delay`, performing the request manually some time ago it worked.
I'm also not sure if using query-based suites could take more time.

Comment: It seems it is a time issue. How about sending the request after you get "200 OK" response?

Comment: Do you mean wait for some time till I get the 200 code from `_apis/test/suites?testCaseId={testCaseId}`?
Because if you are, I'm getting OK status code from there but with the response: `{"value":[],"count":0}`

Comment: I mean wait for some time till getting 200 code from creating/updating TFS test cases. When you get 200 code then sending Get Suites by Test Case ID api.

Comment: Actually I got the 200 code from TFS after sending the batch for test case creation and I also wait for the `workItem.created` event from webhooks before trying to get suites.

Comment: Could you mask the personal information and provide your project? It would be better to include the steps to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this template to get test suites ([Get Suites By Test Case Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/testplan/test%20%20suites/get%20suites%20by%20test%20case%20id?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)): `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/testplan/suites?testCaseId={testCaseId}&api-version=6.1-preview.1`

`testplan` instead of `test` in the url.

If your test case in a test suite, you will receive something like that:

> {"count":1,"value":[{"id":1387,"revision":1,"project":{"id":-259de8150734","name":"project","url":"https://dev.azure.com/org/_apis/projects/project","state":"unchanged","visibility":"unchanged","lastUpdateTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},"lastPopulatedDate":"2021-01-19T16:24:01.36Z","lastUpdatedDate":"2020-08-07T15:05:13.3Z","plan":{"id":1385,"name":"planname"},"_links":{"_self":{"href":"https://dev.azure.com/org/_apis/projects/project/_apis/testplan/Plans/1385/Suites/1387"},"testCases":{"href":"https://dev.azure.com/org/_apis/projects/project/_apis/testplan/Plans/1385/Suites/1387/TestCase"},"testPoints":{"href":"https://dev.azure.com/org/_apis/projects/project/_apis/testplan/Plans/1385/Suites/1387/TestPoint"}},"suiteType":"requirementTestSuite","requirementId":764,"name":"764
> : req","parentSuite":{"id":1386,"name":"test
> suite"},"inheritDefaultConfigurations":true}]}

So that test case in the test plan (ids you can find in the response):

[image]

In your case, `{"value":[],"count":0}` points on one of following:

1. your id is not a test case
2. your test case is not in a test plan

Comment: Hi Shamrai, actually that's a intermittent one because I got such response body before. 
There is no consistent way to reproduce, but if I send few requests to create test cases in sequence or in the same request it usually happens with some of the test cases, and if I send the same request manually some instants later it works.
I'm also able to see the test case in inside the test suite.

Comment: Tried that anyway but was able to reproduce it again:
`Jan 20, 2021 @ 19:37:38.678  -  [TestRunStepOneExecute] data: {"count":0,"value":[]} 

Jan 20, 2021 @ 19:37:38.655  -  [TestRunStepOneExecute] HttpRequestMessage: Method: GET, RequestUri: 'http://..../_apis/testplan/suites?testCaseId=10050139&api-version=5.1-preview.1', Version: 1.1, Content: <null>, Headers:
{
}`